# Error expected unqualified-id before 'do'

Tags: c++

Soy nuevo en programación y me da el error del titulo, quiero crear un código que pida una contraseña.

```
#include<conio.h>
#include<stdio.h>

int c=1234,p;
    do
    {
        system("cls");
        principal();
        gotoxy(25,8);
        printf  ("Capture your password:  ");
        scanf("%d",&p);
        if(p!=c)
        {
            gotoxy(25,16);
            printf  ("Access not allowed  ");
            getch(); // pausa
        }
        
    }
```

Comment: En [tag:c++] no existe el bucle `do`. Existe el bucle `do-while`. En el punto en que cierras la llave del `do` te falta `} while(condición);`.

Answer (score 1):

Como indicaron en el comentario anterior, es necesario usar un ciclo  `do while()`. Un código que usa eso es el siguiente (notar que eliminé la llamada a la función llamada `principal`):

```
#include<conio.h>
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int c=1234,p;
    do
    {
        system("cls");
        gotoxy(25,8);
        printf  ("Capture your password:  ");
        scanf("%d",&p);
        if(p!=c)
        {
            gotoxy(25,16);
            printf  ("Access not allowed  ");
            getch(); // pausa
        }
    }  while(p!=c);
    return 0;
}
```

Al parecer estás usando Turbo C++. Era un excelente compilador, pero es demasiado antiguo (tanto que posiblemente el lenguaje que usa no sea un C++ en regla). Si quieres aprender C++, te recomiendo usar un compilador más reciente, aunque es sólo una recomendación.

Saludos.